# why string is changed to % when I send with post to my server

Tags: python, json, flask, ionic-framework, base64

string that I want to send is

```
let param={"value":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2w"};
this.postHttp("http://202.31.237.173/ionic",param);

postHttp(url: string, param: any = {}) {
    param = this.jsonToURLEncoded(param);
    console.log(param);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept' : 'application/json' });
    //let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    
    //return this.http.post(url, param, options).map((res: Response) => res.json() );
    this.http.post(url, param, options).subscribe((o)=>{
      console.log("subscribe in post http")
    })
   
}
```

but when I received it in my server.
string value is shown as

```
'value=data%3Aimage%2Fjpeg%3Bbase64%2C%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2F2w'
```

it changes / to % ...etc...why is it happened and how to solve it?

server code that receive is as below

```
@app.route("/ionic", methods=['POST']) 
def predictionic():
    
    data = request.get_data()
    print(data);
```

Comment: `/` is changed to `%2F`, that's URL-encoding and it happens because of `param = this.jsonToURLEncoded(param);`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is because you're using the jsonToURLEncoded() function. You dont need to do this, because the params you're encoding is actually the json body. json bodies are jsons, and not part of the url.
The value you're using in the "params" is fine and can be sent and received exactly as you defined it without any further encoding.